# Making a 2d list of objects (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have no experience with object oriented programming. I've program mostly in C so this tends to be a little confusing. Basically I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly. Also, is this a working example of inheritance?

Okay, so I have initialized a 20x20 grid world and set each element to None.

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [[None for x in range(20)] for y in range(20)]
```

Now I need to place an object into a specified element given the x,y coordinates. This is a method of the World class.

```
def add_attack_robot(self, team, x, y, direction):
        self.arr[x][y] = AttackRobot() <---- **Is this correct?**
```

Here is the AttackRobot class:

```
class AttackRobot(Robot):
    def __init__(self,team,x,y,direction):
        Robot.__init__(self,team,x,y,direction)
```

Comment: Your method of indexing the array by ``x, y`` seems okay to me. You basically have a nested list of lists.

Comment: add_attack_robot is a method of the World Class. Since it uses AttackRobot as a subclass would this be inheritance?

Comment: No, inheritance is not what you need here or for other "has a" relationships. A list of lists holding instances is a fine approach.

Comment: See contrived example: http://codepad.org/engstC3X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the list of lists seems sound. Try it yourself in an interpreter (this about the best advice a new Python programmer can take):

```
>>> [[None for x in range(20)] for y in range(20)]
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

When you try to instantiate your `AttackRobot`s, you'll see this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

Pass in valid values for `team`, `x`, `y`, and `direction` (`self` is implicit) and you should be set!

E.g:

```
self.arr[x][y] = AttackRobot(team, x, y, direction)
```